# ActiveMQ Artemis: How to audit (or compute) how much data (by bytes) received by each consumer?

Tags: activemq-artemis

My customer has an ActiveMQ Artemis by which he releases some information to his clients. Now my customer wants to charge his clients by how much data (by bytes) his clients consume.

I wonder whether there is something such as plugin or whatever that can meet my customer's requirement?

Comment: @JustinBertram My best wish is to find a existed package. However, I will still try ActiveMQServerMessagePlugin for the worst case. Thanks.

Comment: As noted in my answer, the existing `LoggingActiveMQServerPlugin` *might* suffice for you. Have you already ruled that out?

Comment: @JustinBertram Regarding developing a class implementing ActiveMQServerMessagePlugin, I have discussed with my team members. Well, my team may try building a POC  for making sure how big the trouble it could be. So, the other solution could be migrating the existed architecture to web service.

Comment: I just had another idea and I updated my answer. I'm not sure why I didn't think of this originally. I believe this will suit your use-case much better than my previous suggestion, and it won't require any development on your part.

Comment: Did you ever have a chance to try out the audit logging?

Answer (score 0):

The best option will be the built-in [audit logging](http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/logging.html#configuring-audit-logging). If you turn on *message* audit logging (i.e. the `org.apache.activemq.audit.message` logger) then the broker will log the username, role, remote address, & message details (including the size) for every message sent, consumed, and acknowledged. Note, some of these details are only available in [2.18.0](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/download/).